# dB formula when input and output resistances are equal

Tags: power-measurement

[image]

Why is the equation of dB voltage gain independent of the input and output resistances? Also, please consider reading the paragraph. I'm not able to understand this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the context here? What kind of a system are we observing exactly?

Comment: Hello @V-Red. Actually it's a generalised formula. But the context can be specified as of electronic communications system.

Answer (score 0):

$$P = { E^2 \over R }$$
so
$${{E_o^2 \over R} \div {E_i^2 \over R}} \implies {E_o^2 \over E_i^2}$$

This only works in the special case that \$(R_i=R_o)\$!

To directly address your question, voltage gain is by definition the open-circuit input and output, so resistances are infinite/not considered.

This goes back to the 2-port model and stuff like that.

Comment: It's just saying that in the special case of Ri and Ro are equal, power gain = voltage gain.